# How to resize the columns table in material ui (v4)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Material Ui(v4) table And what I want is to be able to change the size of the columns,This link is what I want [enter link description here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-column-resizer-forked-01486f?file=/demo.js)

But the problem is how can I have function component insted of class component